# underscores theme - sass folder structure vs smacss

Tags: css, sass

I am using Undescores theme and it comes with the following default SASS folder structure

[image]

I am thinking to implement SMACSS approach to handle CSS.  Since SMACSS uses the following categories - Base, Layout, Modules, State, Theme, would changing Underscores default SASS folder structure into SMACSS one affect theme CSS in any negative way? I was not able to find any tutorial or guide specifically about implementation of the above with Undescores theme.

Comment: You would need to make sure that any import paths are updated. But there’s no reason you shouldn’t be able to use whatever structure you want.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @JacobPeattie. I am new to SASS - my first project. Just to clarify, when you say "any import paths", are you referring to https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use or some other scenarios?

Comment: If you look in style.scss you’ll see it imports the other files. You’d need to make sure those paths are correct if you’re changing directories.

Comment: got it. thanks @JacobPeattie